# Can I stop Glue interactive session automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm using AWS Glue and making jobs.
By recent update Glue interactive session start automatically.
And billing not small amount.
I don't use it at all and want to stop it normaly.
Are there any way?
I think it is a change for the worse. Do you think is it possible to change AWS service policy by user's voice?